# Python RC4 implementation error 'range' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I have limited Python experience though have been asked to use it to implement the RC4 algorithm. I have the following code which seems correct however generates the error

```
'range' object does not support item assignment
```

for the line:

```
S[i], S[j] = S[j], S[i]  # swap
```

Here is my code:

```
def KSA(key):
    keylength = len(key)

    S = range(256)

    j = 0
    for i in S:
        j = (j + S[i] + key[i % keylength]) % 256
        S[i], S[j] = S[j], S[i]  # swap

    return S
```

Comment: Bear in mind that [RC4 is not secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Security). Alternatives without its known weaknesses include [Salsa20](https://cr.yp.to/salsa20.html) and [the eSTREAM recommendations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESTREAM).

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 `range` statement returns a generator object, not a list. Change your initialization line from

```
S = range(256)
```

to

```
S = list(range(256))
```